# Mapbox Power BI circle drill through

Tags: dictionary, geometry, powerbi, mapbox, heatmap

I have a problem, I wanna ask if it's possible to click on Mapbox circle and drill through another page? or are there any ideas of doing so?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, possible. You can right click on the circle and chose the drill through page from available list.

Comment: Hi, i tried it with the drill through function but there is no option of drill through once I right click on the circle. i can see all the data of the tool tip on the circle by left click but I cant drill through. any ideas?

Comment: You have to create the Drill through page first. Then you will get it in the list.

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response, i have the drill through page. I tried it with the pie chart, it works, however It doesn't work on mapbox.. Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to give me .pbix file for the mapbox? you can leave the token of mapbox blank. I would appreciate it cause I really need it. Thanks sir

Comment: Please check my answer below-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample report for you using Map visual with drill down option. Download the sample **pbix** file from [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X6DExvw8tVAlZfPynC1O0IuM9CPwmNQn/view?usp=sharing).

Please let me know if you find any complexity.